# Getting NSinvalid argument exception while consuming a native binding library for xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios-frameworks

So i've been trying to create a Native Binding which can be used in Xamarin Forms, so its been fine, but there's one instance where i'm adding a new

> Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[BTDropInRequest setCardholderNameSetting:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

This is my ApiDefinition class

```
[NullAllowed, Export("cardholderNameSetting", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
        BTFormFieldSetting CardHolderNameSetting { get; set; }
```

And i've defined `BTFormFieldSetting` in Structs as

```
 [Native]
public enum BTFormFieldSetting : long
{
    BTFormFieldDisabled ,
    BTFormFieldOptional,
    BTFormFieldRequired = 0
}
```

and this is my iOS Native equivalent

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BTFormFieldSetting cardholderNameSetting;
```

and this what is defined for `BTFormFieldSetting`

```
    typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, BTFormFieldSetting) {
    BTFormFieldDisabled = 0,
    BTFormFieldOptional,
    BTFormFieldRequired
};

@interface BTDropInRequest : NSObject <NSCopying>
```

I've included the Native Framework for the Binding Library and if i do not use this piece of code it works fine
Any Inputs would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't related to anything technical, but rather needed to resolve all the dependencies related to this, once i did that, everything started working

Answer (score 0):

You are binding to an objective-C property of `BTDropInRequest` that does not `@synthesize` the property, thus it does not generate the setter and getter methods.

IOW, here is the Obj-C source in `BTDropInRequest.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BTFormFieldSetting cardholderNameSetting;
```

Normally when doing this, one would use the `@synthesize` in the `BTDropInRequest.m` implementation file to automatically create the `setCardHolderNameSetting:` selector which allows you to set the property value with

```
[BTDropInRequest setCardholderNameSetting:<Instance of BTFormFieldSetting>]
```

and also create a `cardholderNameSetting` selector which allows one to get the property value. This is not done in the [implementation file of `BTDropInRequest`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-ios-drop-in/blob/master/BraintreeDropIn/Models/BTDropInRequest.m). If it were you would see:

```
@synthesize cardholderNameSetting;
```

but it is not there, hence the error of the missing selector. Not sure how to fix this without changing the Obj-C source code.

Comment: I'm not that good with obj-c ,so correct me if i'm wrong, but the obj-c library seems to work fine on iOS Native though

Comment: I would need to see how the library is used in an Obj-C project and how it is being used in Xam.iOS. I would suggest opening a free 1 on 1 email support case with MS Xamarin support team (I am a member of that team). This way we can privately exchange info, code, etc. You can open a free Xamarin support case here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=classiccommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=16068&forceorigin=esmc&ccsid=636645150473349054

Comment: Hi, was able to fix it, the above method had a lot of dependencies in other libraries which i included and it started working

Comment: Yup, that would do it. :-)